# How to simplify functions in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Hello Let's say I have theres two functions

```
F1= a*x^(2) + b
F2 = c*x
```

Where a, b and c are a constant and x is a variablem how do can I make matlab gives me a simplified version of F1*F2 so the answer may be

```
a*c*x^(3) + b*c*x
```

This is what I have in matlab

```
syms x a b c
F1 = a*x^(2) +b;
F2 = c*x^(2);

simplify(F1*F2)


ans =

c*x^2*(a*x^2 + b)
```

When I multiply in matlab it's just giving me (a*x^(2) + b)*(c*x)

Comment: what it should give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this commands:

```
    syms a x b c
F1= a*x^(2) + b
F2 = c*x
F=F1*F2
collect(F)
```

which will give you:

```
ans =
a*c*x^3 + b*c*x
```

The command `collect` is useful when working with polynoms. The opposite command is `pretty`. It will give you `c*x*(a*x^2 + b)`